# How to specify type for a list

Tags: springdoc

I use spring boot 3 with spring doc

I have this code in my payload

```
@Schema(description="List of duplicate person")
List<DuplicatePersonName> duplicatePersons;
```

How I can specify with the type attribute in schema the data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@ArraySchema`

```java
@ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(description = "List of duplicate person"))
List<DuplicatePersonName> duplicatePersons
```